# Ansible playbook > how to execute different roles with different hosts

Tags: ansible

```
- hosts: filebeat_servers 
  remote_user: x
  roles:
    - install_Filebeat

- hosts: elasticsearch_server
  remote_user: x
  roles:
    - install_Elasticsearch
```

In this code, the same remote_user was repeated twice. In this example it is fine. But what if there are still lots of different roles with the same remote_user? Is there any way to optimize and refactor this code so that the common remote_user is only one line?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you create a group for those hosts:

```
[groupForHostsWithUserX]
filebeat_server
elasticsearch_server
```

And set the remote_user as a group var:

in `/group_vars/groupForHostsWithUserX.yml`:

`remote_user: x`

Comment: sorry that I don't understand what did you mean exactly why the suffix is -servers?

Comment: moreover, how to use this group_vars?

Comment: It's just a name. You can can group any hosts you want into, well, a group. Then set a variable in a file in group_vars and use that anywhere in your tasks/roles/etc. There are other ways to do it, see: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html

Comment: To MattW: I tried it. it seems that in groupForHostsWithUserX.yml, it is only allowed to defined values of variables other than the ansible inherent variables such as remote_user, vars_files (this can also define the values of variables). Is there any more advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use ansible_ssh_user as the inventory variable, not remote_user